# Data Content Observer changes not works in all devices

Tags: android, android-workmanager, android-jobscheduler

Dears,
I implemented content observer for media files by using workerManager API.
Tested in two different devices of the Same model and os (12)
But strangely in one device, we were able to receive change notification after the process was killed.
Not able to receive in another device.

The dumps logs of JobSchedulers of both devices,

**Not Working Device:**

> JOB #u0a101/229: de95f37
>
> com.example.android.test/androidx.work.impl.background.systemjob.SystemJobService
> u0a101 
> tag=*job*/com.example.android.test/androidx.work.impl.background.systemjob.SystemJobService
> Source: uid=u0a101 user=0 pkg=com.example.android.test
> JobInfo:
> Service: com.example.android.test/androidx.work.impl.background.systemjob.SystemJobService
> Flags: 2
> Required constraints: CONTENT_TRIGGER [0x4000000]
> Dynamic constraints: CHARGING BATTERY_NOT_LOW IDLE [0x7]
> Satisfied constraints: BATTERY_NOT_LOW DEVICE_NOT_DOZING WITHIN_QUOTA [0x3000002]
> Unsatisfied constraints: CONTENT_TRIGGER [0x4000000]
>      ....
> Standby bucket: **RESTRICTED**

**Working Device:**

> JOB #u0a101/460: 7d5d7b8
>
> com.example.android.test/androidx.work.impl.background.systemjob.SystemJobService
> u0a101 
> tag=*job*/com.example.android.test/androidx.work.impl.background.systemjob.SystemJobService
> Source: uid=u0a101 user=0 pkg=com.example.android.test
> JobInfo:
> Service: com.example.android.test/androidx.work.impl.background.systemjob.SystemJobService
> Flags: 2
>        .....
> Required constraints: CONTENT_TRIGGER [0x4000000]
> Dynamic constraints:
> Satisfied constraints: DEVICE_NOT_DOZING BACKGROUND_NOT_RESTRICTED WITHIN_QUOTA [0x3400000]
> Unsatisfied constraints: CONTENT_TRIGGER [0x4000000]
>      .....
> Standby bucket: **ACTIVE**

In working device, standby bucket stat is ACTIVE.
How to change Standby bucket state RESTRICTED to ACTIVE state?